# Nodejs unable to detect folder after directory structure change

Tags: node.js, path, discord.js

Our team is working on a discord bot in javascript. Recently I was working on the API (for a dashboard) on a separate branch and then I noticed that commands stopped registering because it could not find the commands directory. This was after a directory change,All of the bot's content was in the root directory before the change but is now in the `bot` directory, I checked if the directory was correct and it was! It didn't work with relative paths but absolute paths work! Here is the code for the command handler (only loading part)

```js
const Categories = ['fun', 'moderation', 'server'];
const commandsDir = path.join('./', 'commands');

logger.info('loading commands...', 'Command_Handler');

Categories.forEach((Category) => {
    fs.readdir(path.join(commandsDir, Category), (error, files) => {
        if (error) {
            logger.error(
                new Error(`Error In Reading Command Files:\n${error}`),
                'Command_Handler'
            );
        } else {
            files.forEach((file) => {
                if (!file.endsWith('.js'))
                    logger.error(
                        new Error(`A File Does Not Ends With .js`, 'Command_Handler')
                    );

                let command = require(path.join(commandsDir, Category, file));

                if (!command.name || !command.aliases)
                    logger.error(
                        new Error(
                            `No Command Name & Command Aliases In A File`,
                            'Command_Handler'
                        )
                    );
                if (command.name) client.commands.set(command.name, command);
                if (command.aliases)
                    command.aliases.forEach(
                        (alias) => client.aliases.set(alias, command.name),
                        logger.success(`registered ${command.name}`, 'Command_Handler')
                    );
                if (command.aliases.length === 0) command.aliases = null;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the directory structure:

[image: Directory structure]

The code is in `index.js`

## Update

I fixed it by replacing `const commandsDir = path.join('./', 'commands');` with `const commandsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question: assuming `commandsDir` changes during the execution - your program will stop working: the way nodejs is working is that every module is loaded only once and cached, so `commandsDir` will be loaded only once and later on when the directory changes, it will continue pointing to the wrong (original) directory.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was looking for! That was my first thought that it is leading to the old directory. What I am trying to say is that we had all the bot's content (everything in the bot folder) in the root directory at one point in time but now have moved everything to the bot directory and here is a extra little bit of info I got after looking into the error more: `D\projects\discord-bots\UnWired\commands` it's scanning that dir instead of the bot dir which is where the command directory used to be.

Comment: Why does the program move the directory? that's a bit of a weird behavior!

Comment: It dosen't move the directory! We changed the directory structure to put the contents of the bot into a separate folder!

Comment: can you not replace `const commandsDir = path.join('./', 'commands');` with `const commandsDir = path.join('./bot', 'commands');` and check? cause as the bot folder is changed but not the working directory.

Comment: Dosen't work! It just goes to the first command and then says module not found

Answer (score 1):

Use `commandsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'commands')` it should work for ts node

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.